# FileNotFound exception in Base64 to Bitmap Android decode

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, filenotfoundexception

First of all, i added the permisions on androidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Im triying to decode a base64 string with this code:

```
private Bitmap decodeImage(String image_data) {
        // Decode the encoded string into largeIcon
        Bitmap largeIcon = null;
        if ((image_data != null) && (!image_data.equals(""))) {
            byte[] decodedImage = Base64.decode(image_data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            if (decodedImage != null) {
                largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedImage
                        , 0
                        , decodedImage.length);
            }
        }
        return largeIcon;
   }
```

But always have the same problem:

```
E/BitmapFactory(10601): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/gATQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsND (BLA BLA BLA) now/ud/p/9k=: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I get the base64 string from a local DB and the Android used to run the app is 4.4.2

I dont know where is the problem! Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: your code seem to be ok no problem if it will get the string it will work

Comment: your code seem to be ok ,as you said that it throwing exception as FileNotFoundException that mean the file is not there where the file path you are passing in the File f=new File(String dir,String Filename); bcz of that only its its throwing exception and your this decodeImage("data"); this code is not called bcz before this only its reach to catch(Exception e) block..so my suggestion is to check out the file path which you are passing to get it the file. ok share the code where you are calling the creating or de-serializing the image object into File or FileInputStream

Comment: Here is the code where I call the method decodeImage: ImageView avatar = (ImageView) view;
     Bitmap avatarImg = decodeImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_IMAGE64)));
     avatar.setImageBitmap(avatarImg);

Comment: String image=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_IMAGE64)) check the value of image in toast or in Log.e("image",image+""); and let me know and please also check when your converting the image into String using decode function what value is coming i.e same value is been store in the db and that value is coming in this Image verify that to ok